# migrating wso2 Identity Server to 5.11.0 from 5.7.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I have a few questions regarding the upgrade of wso2 IS-

1. can we directly upgrade wso2 IS 5.7.0 to 5.11.0?
2. I'm using Postgres for wso2 IS 5.7.0, can I get some reference to changes I need to do in the wso2 configuration while preparing for migration?
3. Do I need to create another database in Postgres for 5.11.0 and then configure it as a datasource in IS?

update:
Im getting following error while performing upgrade-
erver/
[2021-09-20 12:49:26,279] []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.multitenancy.eager.TenantLoadingConfig} - Using tenant lazy loading policy...
[2021-09-20 12:49:26,315] [] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.permission.update.PermissionUpdater} - Error when updating the permission cache for tenant : -1234 java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.permission.update.PermissionUpdater.update(PermissionUpdater.java:72)
at org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.permission.update.PermissionUpdateServiceComponent.activate(PermissionUpdateServiceComponent.java:65)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:113)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:985)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:866)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:804)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:228)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:525)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:544)
at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.initializeCarbon(CarbonServerManager.java:529)
at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.removePendingItem(CarbonServerManager.java:305)
at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.PreAxis2ConfigItemListener.bundleChanged(PreAxis2ConfigItemListener.java:118)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:973)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345)

[2021-09-20 12:49:29,790] []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.internal.IdentityCoreServiceComponent} - Executing Migration client : org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.MigrationClientImpl
[2021-09-20 12:49:29,853] []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.config.Config} -  WSO2 Product Migration Service Task : Loading Migration Configs, PATH:C:\Users\msingh11\DOWNLO~1\WSO2IS~1.0\bin..\migration-resources\migration-config.yaml
[2021-09-20 12:49:29,951] []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.config.Config} -  WSO2 Product Migration Service Task : Successfully loaded the config file.
[2021-09-20 12:49:29,952] []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.Mi}

The deployemnt.toml file is-

```
    [server]
hostname = "localhost"
node_ip = "127.0.0.1"
base_path = "https://$ref{server.hostname}:${carbon.management.port}"

[super_admin]
username = "wso2admin"
password = "admin"
create_admin_account = false


[user_store]
class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager"
connection_url = "ldap://localhost:${Ports.EmbeddedLDAP.LDAPServerPort}"
connection_name = "uid=admin,ou=system"
connection_password = "admin"
user_search_base="ou=Users,dc=wso2,dc=org"
user_name_list_filter="(objectClass\u003dperson)"
user_name_search_filter="(\u0026amp;(objectClass\u003dperson)(uid\u003d?)"
user_name_attribute= "uid"
user_entry_object_class= "identityPerson"
group_entry_object_class= "groupOfNames"
group_name_attribute= "cn"
group_name_search_filter= "(\u0026amp;(objectClass\u003dgroupOfNames)(cn\u003d?))"
group_name_list_filter= "(objectClass\u003dgroupOfNames)"
group_search_base="ou=Groups,dc=wso2,dc=org"
membership_attribute= "member"
anonymous_bind= "false"
display_name_attribute= ""
back_links_enabled= "false"
is_bulk_import_supported= "false"
empty_roles_allowed= "true"
password_hash_method= "PLAIN_TEXT"
kdc_enabled= "false"
default_realm_name= "WSO2.ORG"
connection_pooling_enabled= "true"
lDAP_connection_timeout= "5000"
base_dn = "dc=wso2,dc=org"      #refers the base dn on which the user and group search bases will be generated

[user_store.properties]
TenantManager="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.tenant.CommonHybridLDAPTenantManager"

[database.carbon_db]
type = "RDBMS"
url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/wso2"
username = "wso2admin"
password = "admin"
driver="org.postgresql.Driver"


[database.identity_db]
type = "RDBMS"
url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/wso2"
username = "wso2admin"
password = "admin"
driver="org.postgresql.Driver"

[database.shared_db]
type = "RDBMS"
url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/wso2"
username = "wso2admin"
password = "admin"
driver="org.postgresql.Driver"

[keystore.primary]
file_name = "wso2carbon.jks"
password = "wso2carbon"

[truststore]
file_name="client-truststore.jks"
password="wso2carbon"
type="JKS"

[account_recovery.endpoint.auth]
hash= "66cd9688a2ae068244ea01e70f0e230f5623b7fa4cdecb65070a09ec06452262"

[identity.auth_framework.endpoint]
app_password= "dashboard"

[[datasource]]
id="source"
url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/wso2"
username="wso2admin"
password="admin"
driver="org.postgresql.Driver"
[datasource.pool_options]
maxActive="80"
maxWait="60000"
minIdle="5"
testOnBorrow="true"
validationQuery="SELECT 1"
validationInterval="30000"
defaultAutoCommit="false"

[[datasource]]
id="target"
url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/wso2_new"
username="wso2admin"
password="admin"
driver="org.postgresql.Driver"
[datasource.pool_options]
maxActive="80"
maxWait="60000"
minIdle="5"
testOnBorrow="true"
validationQuery="SELECT 1"
validationInterval="30000"
defaultAutoCommit="false"
# The KeyStore which is used for encrypting/decrypting internal data. By default the primary keystore is used as the internal keystore.

#[keystore.internal]
#file_name = "$ref{keystore.primary.file_name}"
#type = "$ref{keystore.primary.type}"
#password = "$ref{keystore.primary.password}"
#alias = "$ref{keystore.primary.alias}"
#key_password = "$ref{keystore.primary.key_password}"

# The KeyStore which is used for tls communication. By default the primary keystore is used as the tls keystore.

#[keystore.tls]
#file_name = "$ref{keystore.primary.file_name}"
#type = "$ref{keystore.primary.type}"
#password = "$ref{keystore.primary.password}"
#alias = "$ref{keystore.primary.alias}"
#key_password = "$ref{keystore.primary.key_password}"

#Google reCAPTCHA settings.

#[recaptcha]
#enabled = "true"
#api_url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"
#verify_url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify"
#site_key = ""
#secret_key = ""

# SMTP email sender settings.
#[output_adapter.email]
#from_address= "abcd@gmail.com"
#username= "abcd"
#password= "xxxx"
#hostname= "smtp.gmail.com"
#port= 587
```

what I'm missing in the config?

Answer (score 1):

> Can we directly upgrade `wso2is-5.7.0` to `wso2is-5.11.0`?

Yes, but you need to do few steps to configure the migration from `wso2is-5.7.0` to `wso2is-5.11.0`

1. Make sure that all the prerequisites are met, you can see the prerequisites from [here](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/setup/migration-guide/)
2. Next do the pre-steps for the migration by following the details in [here](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/setup/migrating-preparing-for-migration/)
3. For the resources like the custom components, custom libraries, Keystore managers, tenants, etc. follow the link in [here](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/setup/migrating-to-5110/)

> I'm using `Postgres` for `wso2is-5.7.0`, can I get some reference >to changes I need to do in the wso2 configuration while preparing >for migration?

If you are using the  `Postgres`, during the migration, `uuid-ossp` extension is created in the database. In order to create this extension, the database user should have the `superuser` permission. If the user is not already a superuser, assign the permission before starting the migration.

```
ALTER USER <user> WITH SUPERUSER;
```

> Do I need to create another database in Postgres for `wso2is-5.11.0` and then
> configure it as a data source in IS?

No, you don't want to create another database in `Postgres` for 5.11.0 and configure it, but for the safety measures, you can have a snapshot of your 5.7.0 database and plug it in the 5.11.0

Comment: what is the need for the following step, can you please explain-                                           
 To migrate the super tenant, copy the content from <OLD_IS_HOME>/repository/deployment/server directory to the <NEW_IS_HOME>/repository/deployment/server directory.

Comment: it will contain all the `webapps` and all the changes that you did for the super tenant, which is `carbon.super` tenant

Comment: can you please look into the update section